# Remove '@' from E-mail Regex

Tags: regex, email

I want to validate the E-mail regex without the `@` character such that after removal, `test.com` would be the valid e-mail ID and the regex should report error when using `@` character. Here's the Regex I am working upon...

```
  [a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?
```

This regex is matching `test@test.com`.
But i want regex that match `test.com` only, not with `@`.

I tried several things but nothing working out. Any help would be appreciated.
I am using online tools for validation.

**EDIT**    - 
Forget E-mail regex.
What could be used to remove `@` character in normal regex.

Comment: Regular expressions match patterns rather than "report error"s. Are you just trying to match something.com? If so, something like .*\.com would work.

Comment: Can you include a handful of both matching and non matching email addresses?  Your regex is too long IMO to ask someone here to digest.

Comment: If you want a regex to validate email addresses that shouldn't accept email addresses then you aren't validating email addresses. You should edit the question and explain what you want to validate (and what its rules should be).

Comment: I tried to correct the question

Comment: That feels extraordinarily similar to validating domain names. Is there any difference?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález actually i'have been given a assignment to test email address , and i want to test with the regex that don't accept  `@` character

Comment: A regex that does not accept `@` is `^[^@]*$`. Expanding to `no@.no@` => `^[^@.]*\.[^@]*$`